# checking data availability before calling std::getline

Tags: c++, iostream

I would like to read some data from a stream I have using `std::getline`.
Below a sample using the `std::cin`.

```
std::string line;
std::getline( std::cin, line );
```

This is a blocking function i.e. if there is no data or line to read it blocks execution.

Do you know if exists a function for checking data availability before calling `std::getline`? I don't want to block.

How can I check whether the stream buffer is full of data valid for a successful call to `std::getline`?

Whatever looks like the code below

```
if( dataAvailableInStream() )
{
     std::string line;
     std::getline( std::cin, line );
}
```

Comment: You say you don't want to block, but your example uses std::cin. Tell us what are you trying to accomplish and maybe we can clarify our answers to be more helpful.

Comment: Hi All! I have a blocking istream. In the specific I am using POCO library for processes and I want to read from POCO::PipeInputStream.
My question was :
1. I know that calling std::getline with a blocking stream would block if no data is available
2. what function to call to check if data is available
3. if NO data is available I am not going to call std::getline because it blocks

Comment: (This still shows up in search results.) See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42264216/1599699

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `iostream` library doesn't support the concept of non-blocking I/O.  I don't think there's anything in the C++ standard that does.  Any good solution would likely be platform-specific.  If you can use the POSIX libraries, you might look into [`select`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/select).  It's usually used for networking stuff, but it'll work just fine if you pass it the file descriptor for stdin.

Answer (score 18):

There is no standard way to verify if `getline` will block. You can use:

```
std::cin.rdbuf()->in_avail()
```

to see how many characters are definitely available before a read operation may block, but you would have to read the characters one by one before re-checking `in_avail` as there is no way to know in advance if any of the pending characters is a newline or the actual end of the stream. A `getline` call might block if this wasn't the case.

Note that although if `in_avail()` returns a postive number there are guaranteed that at least that many characters are available before the end of the stream, the converse is not true. If `in_avail()` returns zero there may still be characters available and the stream might not block immediately.

Comment: This does not work terribly well with MSVC 2013. It seems to return a positive value even when the stream is not closed and no input is available. I won't waste a day testing it, but I definitely think it's rotten.

Comment: "I definitely think it's rotten." -- What, MSVC? ;-)

Comment: @kuroineko you're right, it doesn't work. It returns 0 whatever the condition of the stream, piped or TTY. If you call `peek()` on `cin` first, then `in_avail` starts to return interesting data. But in TTY (not piped) `peek` blocks on input and awaits a Ctrl+Z. (yes. peek blocks, it's insane). MSVC 2019.

Answer (score 9):

This code can help you to check existence of data in the `stdin` without blocking:

```
std::cin.seekg(0, std::cin.end);
int length = std::cin.tellg();
if (length < 0) return; //- no chars available
```

If `stdin` has some data - don't forget to set the position back to the beginning.

```
std::cin.seekg(0, std::cin.beg);
```

You can then read all data including `\0` (can be more than one) at the end of the buffer:

```
std::vector<char> s(length);
std::cin.read(s.data(), length);
```

or line by line:

```
std::string line;
while (std::cin) {
    std::getline(std::cin, line);
    //.....
}
```

This code works in MSVC and gcc (Ubuntu)

Comment: OMG I've been searching all day for some way to detect a console application has a pipe input present, reading hundreds of answers stating this isn't possible. TY! So far this is working great.

Answer (score 2):

A hack could be to call kbhit() before the read.  Probably not portable and fraught with danger...

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


char buffer[128];

if (kbhit())
{
     cin.getline(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What problem are you trying to solve by avoiding the read blocking here?

Non-portably I imagine you could use `poll` or `select` to see if there's data to read on stdin (often fd 0 on unix systems).

Alternately you could create a second thread to do I/O and just let it block so you can continue normal processing in the main thread.

Comment: if I use a second thread, for what I know there are issue in killing thread, so better to live it until the end of the application.
Does this make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Although nathan's `peek()` answer will see if there is data, there is no guarantee that `std::getline()` will be successful in reading a "line".

It is always much easier albeit a bit backwards to try getline and check the result of thee function call itself:

```
std::string line;
while( !std::getline(std::cin, line) )
{
    cout << "Enter something please" << endl;
}
```

This code will run until `cin` receives something it likes (ie can extract and place in `line`). I don't see `peek()` being necessary or useful here.

EDIT: The thing is, `cin` (==standard keyboard input) will have to block the program as it waits for input, how else can it get any input when it wouldn't wait?

Comment: Good point about cin, I had not considered that it would block.

Answer (score -2):

std::iostream provides a peek function that returns the next character in the stream without removing it. So you could do something like the following (totally not tested).

```
bool dataAvailableInStream( std::iostream &stream )
{
  return stream.peek() != std::iostream::traits_type::eof();
}
```

**Edit**

As rubenvb points out, `std::cin` blocks by design. Therefore the code above will get you past `getline` blocking, but not `cin`.

**Edit Edit**

As Charles points out below, `peek` blocks if no data is available. Therefore this does not provide a complete solution.  It will keep you from blocking on `getline`, but not blocking overall.

Comment: Or `return stream.peek() != std::eof;` if you're not into verbosity.

Comment: IT DOESN'T WORK!
I tried and peek() blocks as std::getline() does when there is nothing to read.

Comment: This is incorrect. `peek()` only returns `traits_type::eof()` if reading the peeked character fails. If the character takes a long time to read (blocked on user input), `peek()` will just take a long time to return.

Comment: @Abruzzo, as others have pointed out cin blocks. Other stream types, say if you were reading from a file, would not block.

Comment: @Charles, I've reverted the std::eof to the traits_type::eof I had originally.

Comment: Um, there is no `std::traits_type`, I was being short for `std::iostream::traits_type`. That's not the major issue though. "If there is no character it returns an eof trait" is not true. If there is no character `peek()` just blocks in exactly the same way that `get()` would block. `peek()` simply doesn't address the issue that the asker is having.

Comment: hi all. Please see my note afeter nathan comment right after the question. Apologize to everybody, but I was out for today so I am late.

Comment: @Charles, thanks for double checking me. I think I've corrected the answer enough to provide a partial solution to Abruzzo's problem.

Comment: You've still missed of the brackets from the `eof()` call :) .  I'm still not convinced how much this answer addresses the original problem as the question definitely calls for an approach that is guaranteed to not block.

Comment: True, but the way the question is asked it sounded, at least to me, the main issue was that `getline` was blocking while waiting on a newline character. The `peek` call would remedy that.

Comment: How would it remedy the problem? Even if your `dataAvailableInStream` doesn't block and doesn't return `... .eof()`, there's no guarantee that there's a `\n` somewhere in the available input characters. `std::getline` might still block. If there are no characters available your function might itself block which is another reason that it doesn't address the problem. Am I being really slow because obviously you have some upvotes; I just can't see how your function is supposed to help?

Comment: You're right, my function would only give the existence of data, but that was specifically what the author asked for "Do you know if exists a function for checking data availability before calling std::getline? I don't want to block." Once the function returned true, the author would then have to check if the available character is a newline, before calling getline.  Should I add that portion to my answer, would that make it somewhat clearer?

Comment: Yes, but he explicitly states "I don't want to block"; that's his motivation for a checking function. If the checking function itself might block; doesn't that make it an inappropriate solution regardless?

Comment: I'm not sure he can get a whole solution using an iostream that blocks. From my brief scan of POCO::PipeInputStream it blocks on rdbuf() calls as well. I don't see the solution as inappropriate given the information in the question.  That's why I asked the motivation for not blocking. I guess I'm the one being slow :).

Comment: Just because `std::istream` is a blocking interface doesn't mean that all functions block. For example, `std::streambuf::in_avail()` is non-blocking and could be used in a possible partial solution to the problem. Admittedly, it is not clear from POCO documentation whether the POCO BasicStreamBuf class has a conforming `showmanyc` override.