# How to assert if a std::mutex is locked?

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, c++11

With GCC 4.8.2 (on Linux/Debian/Sid 64 bits) -or GCC 4.9 when available - in C++11- I have some mutex

```
std::mutex gmtx;
```

<sup>actually, it is a `static` member in some class `Foo` containing both `alpha` and `beta` methods below.</sup>

it is locked in `alpha` like

```
void alpha(void) {
   std::lock_guard<std::mutex> g(gmtx);
   beta(void);
   // some other work
}
```

and I want to check in `beta` that indeed `gmtx` is locked:

```
void beta(void) {
   assert (gmtx.is_locked());
   // some real work
}
```

<sup>(notice that `is_locked` is only called inside `assert`... It can be very inefficient or even sometimes inaccurate)</sup>

Of course, I have other functions calling `beta`, e.g.

```
void gamma(void) {
   std::lock_guard<std::mutex> g(gmtx);
   beta();
   // some other work
}
```

but `is_locked` does not exist.... How should I define it? (actually I would like to be sure that the mutex has been locked in the same thread by some [indirect] caller...)

(the reason I want to test that with `assert` is that `beta` could be called elsewhere)

I cannot use `try_lock` (unless using recursive mutexes), because in the common case it would lock an already locked mutex... (locked in the same thread by a caller) and this is not only undefined behavior but blocks entirely.

I want to avoid recursive mutexes (more costly than plain mutexes) unless I really have to.

---

<sup>NB: The real program is a bit more complex. Actually, all the methods are inside a class which maintain a naming bi-directional relation on "items". So I have inside that class a map from items to names and another from names to items. `beta` would be the internal method adding really a naming, and `alpha` and `gamma` would be the methods finding -or adding- an item by its name, or a name by its item.</sup>

<sup>PS: the real program is not yet released, but should become part of [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) - its future [monitor](http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/jit/2013-q4/msg00025.html); you can download it (alpha stage, very buggy) from [here](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/monimelt-19feb2014.tgz) (a temporary location)</sup>

Comment: if `beta` requires that the mutex is always locked (as your `assert` suggests) why are you pushing that responsibility up the call chain?

Comment: Because (as I edited) some other function like `gamma` would call `beta` ...

Comment: Right I see, but both are required to lock the mutex before calling beta, so why is beta not just locking the mutex?  Are you saying that both callers have other work to do that requires the mutex be locked?

Comment: @JohnLedbetter: Yes, both callers do real work.

Comment: I have the same use case here. Strange that there is an owns_lock on the lock class but not on the mutex. I can spend a question on Boost forum.

Comment: Wrap the lock in a class that maintains a 'locked' boolean variable and check that?

Comment: @gast128 The C++ mutex is designed to be an absolute minimum implementation to map efficiently to low level / OS level constructs. There's an overhead to tracking which thread owns the lock and there's a correct assumption that if we're using concurrency the aim is to strictly (aggressively) minimise overheads. Most good designs never need to check if they own a mutex. The control flow is implemented to ensure correct behaviour. You can add it to your own 'lockable' wrapper but it wouldn't be possible to subtract it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`std::unique_lock<L>` has `owns_lock` member function (equivalent of `is_locked` as you say).

```
std::mutex gmtx;
std::unique_lock<std::mutex> glock(gmtx, std::defer_lock);

void alpha(void) {
   std::lock_guard<decltype(glock)> g(glock);
   beta(void);
   // some other work
}
void beta(void) {
   assert(glock.owns_lock()); // or just assert(glock);
   // some real work
}
```

**EDIT:** In this solution, all lock operations should be performed via unique_lock `glock` not 'raw' mutex `gmtx`. For example, `alpha` member function is rewritten with `lock_guard<unique_lock<mutex>>` (or simply `lock_guard<decltype(glock)>`).

Comment: Concurrently calling `lock()`/`unlock()` on a `unique_lock` from different threads results in a data race, which makes this rather useless.

Comment: `std::unique_lock` is not thread safe and is not meant to be used in multiple threads. The implementation I have seen stores a bool value of whether it owns the lock solely based on `lock()` and `unlock()` calls, independent of the calling thread. Therefore, locking a global `std::unique_lock` in one thread will make `owns_lock()` return true for **every** thread, which is very incorrect behavior.

Comment: This isn't really workable.  Typically the lock guard is on the stack in some method, not a member of the class, and there may be many lock guards in many threads.  I think what the OP really wants to know is "does THIS thread have the mutex locked?"

Answer (score 23):

Strictly speaking, the question was about checking the lockedness of `std::mutex` directly. However, if encapsulating it in a new class is allowed, it's very easy to do so:

```
class mutex :
    public std::mutex
{
public:
#ifndef NDEBUG
    void lock()
    {
        std::mutex::lock();
        m_holder = std::this_thread::get_id(); 
    }
#endif // #ifndef NDEBUG

#ifndef NDEBUG
    void unlock()
    {
        m_holder = std::thread::id();
        std::mutex::unlock();
    }
#endif // #ifndef NDEBUG

#ifndef NDEBUG
    bool try_lock()
    {
        if (std::mutex::try_lock()) {
            m_holder = std::thread::id();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
#endif // #ifndef NDEBUG

#ifndef NDEBUG
    /**
    * @return true iff the mutex is locked by the caller of this method. */
    bool locked_by_caller() const
    {
        return m_holder == std::this_thread::get_id();
    }
#endif // #ifndef NDEBUG

private:
#ifndef NDEBUG
    std::atomic<std::thread::id> m_holder = std::thread::id{};
#endif // #ifndef NDEBUG
};
```

Note the following:

1. In release mode, this has zero overhead over `std::mutex` except possibly for construction/destruction (which is a non-issue for mutex objects).
2. The `m_holder` member is only accessed between taking the mutex and releasing it. Thus the mutex itself serves as the mutex of `m_holder`. With very weak assumptions on the type `std::thread::id`, `locked_by_caller` will work correctly.
3. Other standard library types like `std::lock_guard` are templates, so they work well with this new class, because it satisfies the [*Mutex*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Mutex) requirement.

Comment: for `locked_by_caller` to be of any use you have to be able to call it even, when you haven't locked the mutex yourself. so `m_holder` needs to be an atomic for this code to be legal.

Comment: I think this is the best solution and I use something like this too. Any reason why didn't update `m_holder` type to atomic as suggested?

Comment: This is rife with race conditions. Because the lock/unlock is not performed atomically with the setting of the locker.

Comment: I revise my comment on further thought.  This has some race conditions, because the lock/unlock is not performed atomically with the setting of the locker.  Is does reliably answer the question "does THIS thread have the mutex locked", which is probably what the OP wanted.  It doesn't reliably answer the question "does some other thread have the mutex locked"

Comment: hi. shouldn't m_holder = std::this_thread::get_id() be after successful try_lock instead of std::thread::id()?

Answer (score 15):

You could just use a `recursive_mutex`, which can be locked multiple times on the same thread.  Note: If it were my code, I would restructure it so that I don't need a `recursive_mutex`, but it will address your problem.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: look at it this way -- if a mutex can detect whether or not it is locked by this thread, then it can already implement recursive locking with no further significant time overhead. Therefore, a hypothetical mutex with the property you desire will not slow the code down any less than using a recursive mutex.

Comment: A caution with recursive_mutex is that it cannot be used as the lock for condition_variable but other than that it is a good answer.  It doesn't directly answer the OP's question -- checking if my thread already owns the lock, but it presumably avoids the bad condition (altering data structures without holding the lock).

Answer (score 2):

Well, if the expense of the assertion really isn't an issue then you can just call `try_lock()` from another thread where its behavior is guaranteed to be well defined:

```
void beta(void) {
  assert(std::async(std::launch::async, [] { return gmtx.try_lock(); })
                 .get() == false &&
         "error, beta called without locking gmtx");
  // some real work
}
```

Comment: Because if you lock twice a non-recursive mutex from the same thread the second lock seems to block entirely...

Comment: Deadlocking is not guaranteed, though. It's simply UB.

Comment: It's UB if the thread that calls `try_lock` already owns the mutex.

Comment: @BrettHale Ah, I see. I hadn't checked the spec and my implementation doesn't deadlock.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch there, a version with well defined behavior.

Comment: This does not work.  try_lock on std::mutex when it is already locked by THIS thread is undefined; if nice it throws std::system_exception

Comment: @Wheezil The code never calls `try_lock` on a thread that might already have locked the mutex.

Comment: @bames53 in the example given by OP, gamma() locks, gamma() calls beta(), beta() checks.  So yes, it is exactly that case.

Comment: @Wheezil Nope: my definition of beta launches a new thread and the check is done on that thread. Therefore it is impossible for that thread to already hold the lock.

Answer (score 2):

Try [atomic](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/atomic/atomic/) (e.g. `atomic<bool>` or `atomic<int>`), which has a nice [load](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/atomic/atomic/load/) function that will do what you want, as well as other nice functions like compare_exchange_strong.

Comment: Wow, just ended two hours of research and found that I had upvoted this answer long ago...coming to the same conclusion. Although, I'm beginning to think that extending `std::mutex` might be a good way to go...ugh why isn't this functionality on `std::mutex` already?

Comment: @LimitedAtonement I had found in my experience that atomic was easiest and most straightforward to use.

Comment: @LimitedAtonement Also, if you want to see an example of this in action, I have another answer (that someone just upvoted so I just remembered it) that puts atomic into good use, for asynchronous Console input: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42264216/1599699

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question, but I also find that using atomics can help solve this class of problems.

Comment: @Wheezil From what I remember, the `atomic` class could basically satisfy any multi-threading challenges one would have. Also, according to my answer, the `load()` function will actually do exactly what the OP wants, which I believe is true.

Comment: @Wheezil `while (atomicBool) {}`?

Comment: @Andrew Yes, of course!  Spin lock. That will work just fine so long as your wait time is expected to be small (such as guarding a data structure) or there are lots of cores to burn.  I should have said "won't block the thread and free up the CPU resource".  IIRC correctly, a lot of mutex implementations do a bit of spin before asking the OS to intervene.

Answer (score 2):

It's not technically an assertion, but I've used a similar approach to prevent unlocked access to shared state: add a reference parameter to the lock guard class on the in the unsafe function (beta in your example). Then the function cannot be called unless the caller has created a lock guard. It solves the problem of accidentally calling the function outside of the lock, and it does so at compile time with no races.

So, using your example:

```
typedef std::lock_guard<std::mutex> LockGuard;
void alpha(void) {
   LockGuard g(gmtx);
   beta(g);
   // some other work
}

void beta(LockGuard&) {
   // some real work
}

void gamma(void) {
   LockGuard g(gmtx);
   beta(g);
   // some other work
}

//works recursively too
void delta(LockGuard& g)
{
   beta(g);
}
```

Drawbacks:

- Does not validate that the lock actually wraps the correct mutex.
- Requires the dummy parameter. In practice, I usually keep such unsafe functions private so this is not an issue.

Comment: I like your approach, another advantage of which is that the need for a mutex lock is documented by the parameter list.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `std::unique_lock` and its method `.mutex()` to check what mutex it holds.

```
std::mutex mtx;

void alpha() {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(mtx);
    beta(lck);
}

void beta(std::unique_lock<std::mutex>& lck) {
    assert(lck.mutex() == &mtx);
}
```

in this case you also will see `beta(...)` needs some lock before call.

Answer (score -3):

My solution is simple, use try_lock to test then unlock if needed:

```
std::mutex mtx;

bool is_locked() {
   if (mtx.try_lock()) {
      mtx.unlock();
      return false;
   }
   return true; // locked thus try_lock failed
}
```

Comment: This does not work.  try_lock on std::mutex when it is already locked by THIS thread is undefined and typically throws std::system_exception