# How can I break a loop when a specific character has been hit?

Tags: c++, loops, getchar

Assume I have a loop like

```
for(int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
{
    crunch_data(i);

    if(i_has_been_hit())
        break;
}
```

and I would like to exit the loop whenever I hit <kbd>i</kbd> on the keyboard. Now the following approach won't work, since `std::cin` blocks:

```
bool i_has_been_hit(){
    char a;
    std::cin >> a;
    return a == 'i';
}
```

Is there a function which enables me to check whether the keyboard has been hit without blocking? If it makes any difference, I'm using g++ on Win32 with CodeBlocks.

Comment: I think what you want is cin.get(a);

Comment: Not true,this is stop the loop while i have to eter a char

Comment: PLZ answer,i want my loop running and when i punch a button my loop will  break

Comment: Afaik there is no platform independend way to do this. Do you have to use it for multiple systems?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3317740/checking-data-availability-before-calling-stdgetline

Comment: You may have to use 'curses' for this. I don't think there is a good platform independent way to do this.

Comment: i don't want thread or multiplatform

Comment: then it would be a good time to specify the platform you're using in your question ;)

Comment: my loop printing the " HI",it dosen't wait for my Entering,when i want ,i Enter a char and my loop will break,this is what i want

Comment: @user3260217: Specify your platform. Win32? POSIX? What compiler?

Comment: g++,gcc,i do this in codeblocks IDE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Win32 with `conio.h` available, you can use the usual `kbhit()` and `getch()` combination:

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(){
  for(int i=0;i<100000;i++)
  {
      std::cout<<"Hi";
      if(kbhit() && getch() == 'i'){
          break;
      }
      // other code
  }
}
```

Comment: @user3260217: You would have gotten answers sooner if your question's quality was higher. Please try to write the perfect question next time, see http://java.dzone.com/articles/how-write-perfect and https://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx for guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean a perfect non-blocking I/O model ?? If so its hard to achive and i dont know any existing ways to do it, But u can do something like this

use  **_kbhit()**

```
for(int i=0;i<100000;i++)
{
    cout<<"Hi";
    while (true) {
          if (_kbhit()) {
        char a = _getch();
        // act on character a in whatever way you want
    }

    Sleep(100);
    if(a=='i')
       break;
}
```

Comment: my loop printing the " HI",it dosen't wait for my Entering,when i want ,i Enter a char and my loop will break,this is what i want

Comment: title says "How to get character without stop loop in c++". Perhaps you should make up your mind

Comment: :) SOLVED ,sorry i will never make this mistake