# Stopping while-loop with std::cin input

Tags: c++, while-loop, cin

I'm currently trying to create a loop that should only stop if the user enters "quit", "Quit" or something similar. I tried a few variations already but I need it to execute the rest of the loop and not stop to wait for an Input.

```
Running = true;
while(Running)
  {
    char c;
    std::cout << "test ";
    c = std::cin.peek(); 
    if(c=='Q'|| c=='q')
    {
    Running = false;
    }
  }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You probably meant to write `c = std::cin.peek();` Also you should tell us what else is wrong with that code.

Comment: Yeah I did. It prints "test" once. If I press enter I can't stop the loop. If I enter "quit" after the first "test" it work. I want it to print "test" endlessly until I enter "quit". Sorry if I wasn't clear enough.

Comment: Maybe this is worth reading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3317740/checking-data-availability-before-calling-stdgetline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from `peek()` returning `int_type`, not `char`...

...it *[reads the next character from the stream without actually extracting it](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/peek)*.

Since your `cin` does, at this point, *not contain anything* (unless you piped something to your program, or already typed something), the call will *block* until there *is* a character to be `peek()`ed.

Since, using `<iostream>`, your program does not actually *receive* input *until you press <kbd>Enter</kbd>*, that is what your program does: Waiting until you entered something, and pressed <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Only *then* does the program check whether the first character you entered is "q" or "Q". The *line* you entered, including that first character, *will remain in the stream* -- so the next time you `peek()`, it will still be the very same character.

Solution? There is no non-blocking query of `cin` in the C++ standard library. You either have to work with threads, or refer to some third-party input handling (like the `getch()` function offered by e.g. Microsoft Windows or the [NCurses](https://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/) library).

Comment: @volerag: Damn it, they've *changed* the label of the bloody key since the C64? Tells you how long it's been since I stopped looking. :-D

Answer (score 0):

Do it simply this way.

```
std::string input;
cin>>input;
while(input!="quit" && input!="Quit")
{
// do something;
// get input.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by

> I need it to execute the rest of the loop and not stop to wait for an Input.

But if you replace `c=std::cin.peek()` by `std::cin >> c`, infinite loop problem will be solved.

```
Running = true;
while (Running)
{
    char c; 
    std::cin >> c;
    std::cout << "test";

    if (c == 'Q' || c == 'q')
    {
        Running = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I want the loop to continue if there is no input, but stop if there is "quit". I guess I'm looking for some kind of interrupt thing ?

Comment: Define 'quit' because I am still not sure. Maybe loop continues till count is 10,100...?