# Check user internet connection while there is a cin in progress

Tags: c++

Hi today i was trying to **constantly check the connectivity of users while there is a cin**..

this is the code:

```
while (true)
{
    if (InternetCheckConnection(networkBuffer, FLAG_ICC_FORCE_CONNECTION, 0) != false)
    {
        while (cin >> userInput)
        {
            cout << "> " << userInput << endl;
        }
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
```

I'm sure that the problem is cin but i have to check constantly the users connectivity (also while there is a cin in progress).
Is it possible to do such a thing?

Thanks.

Comment: You need to use threads.

Comment: Many platforms have ways to do this other than threads. But threads is probably the easiest way if you're using a platform that supports `std::thread`.

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/thread/thread/

Comment: You may find a solution in this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3317740/checking-data-availability-before-calling-stdgetline .